# Странное поведение Application.Quit();

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

На андроиде метод `Application.Quit()` не выходит полностью из приложения, оно просто сворачивается и выкидывает на рабочий стол, если развернуть его, оно пойдёт на рестарт.

Каким образом можно полностью выйти из приложения?

Upd: Нашёл еще такой метод, но он показывает тот же результат `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Upd2: После нажатия на кнопку в игре вызывается этот код:

```
public void ExitGame()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    Appication.Quit();
#else
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Так и должно быть. Вы видите недавние приложения. Если наличие приложения в недавних сильно мешает, то решение есть, но это и вопрос другой, и антипаттерн. В общем чем вас текущее поведение не устраивает? В iOS пошли дальше, и сам метод Application.Quit вызывать нельзя по правилам. В Андроиде кстати тоже юзеру проще свернуть и смахнуть, чем искать кнопку выхода)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в Андройде так себя все приложения ведут. Там несколько иное отношение к оперативе - приложение из неё чистится только, когда нужна память. а всё остальное время данные хранятся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сталкивался с похожей проблемой, когда после `Application.Quit()` не завершались корректно процессы, относящиеся к IAP, и после перезапуска IAP не инициализировались. Поэтому завершал приложение таким способом:

```
void customQuit() {
    using(AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    using(AndroidJavaObject javaActivity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")) {
        javaActivity.Call<bool>("moveTaskToBack", true);
        javaActivity.Call("finish");
    }
}
```

P.S. В последних версиях Unity 2018 это исправили.